# CMake file for .cpp+.cu files

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, cmake

I am new to opencv and CMake. I have a .cpp file which pre processes a given image into a a pair of uchar or uint8 arrays on both the host and the device. The first array contains the original image value intensities(both on the host and device). The second array contains a simple inversion (255-pixel value) performed on the device then copied on to the device later.

I wrote my CMakefile to find the cuda executable and link against the main cpp file. But I get an error in which the "main" function is not found. The error is like `relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11`

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 project( preProcess )
 find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
 find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
 include(FindCUDA)

 include_directories(/usr/local/cuda/include)
 set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)

 file( GLOB  cu  *.cu)
 add_executable( preProcess preProc.cpp )
 CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${preProcess} ${cu})
 target_link_libraries(preProcess /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I check my Makefile there is no nvcc command. If you could guide me how to create a CMakeLists.txt file for a project with both cpp files and cu files and link them together or elaborate what I'm doing wrong in my CMakeLists file, it'll be great.

(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 7 and opencv 2.4.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **all** your files to `cuda_add_executable`:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html

> All of the non CUDA C files are compiled using the standard
>      build rules specified by CMAKE and the cuda files are compiled to object files using nvcc and the host compiler.

```
project( preProcess )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)

file( GLOB  cu  *.cu)
cuda_add_executable( preProcess preProc.cpp ${cu} )
target_link_libraries( preProcess ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: GLOB is not CUDA specific, see http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html : "GLOB will generate a list of all files that match the globbing expressions and store it into the variable."

Comment: Thanks. The compilation worked, but unfortunately I think something's wrong with my CUDA kernel

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324054/cuda-image-pixel-invertion-function-doesnt-work

Comment: Is it possible to use CMake to specify that some of the .cpp files should be treated as .cu files?

Comment: @user2023370 yes this can be done through `CUDA_SOURCE_PROPERTY_FORMAT`. If you need a more elaborate answer, please ask a new question.